# Spring Boot 2 - Seems like proxyTargetClass=true is being ignored (cannot cast proxied entities)

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot

This is a spring-boot-starter-web and hibernate/jpa project. In some of my JPA entities, in my equals() implementations, I need to cast the object being compared to the concrete entity class. However, I'm getting proxied entities that cannot be cast because, I suppose, it is using interfaces instead of subclasses regardless of my configuration. In other words, it *seems* like my proxyTargetClass=true configuration is being ignored (I get the exact same error whether that config is there or not).

```
log.info(Hibernate.getClass(equalsObj)); //"com.myco.MyObject"
MyObject casted = (MyObject) equalsObj;
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.myco.MyObjectSuperClass_$$_jvstbeb_28 cannot be cast to com.myco.MyObject
```

In my application.yml, I have..

```
spring.aop.proxy-target-class=true
```

In my java configuration, I also have..

```
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass = true)
```

In my pom.xml, I have...

```
<dependency>
<groupId>cglib</groupId>
<artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
<version>3.2.6</version>
```

An idea what I might be doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: I think that [Spring Boot issue #12194](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/12194) explains your problem. Sorry for the bad news.